# Jsoup ignore nested tags when using select

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse a site that uses

```
 <b>Header</b>Data<strong>Header</strong>Data
```

so I have a selector that is

```
.select("b, strong")
```

and then try to extract the text between. - Everything is fine.

Problem: Sometimes the site has eg.

```
<strong><strong>HeaderX</strong><br /></strong>Data
```

now this messes with my loops since I will get text headerX twice, how can I ignore the nested strong?

**UPDATE #1**
Solved, but probably has some better way.

```
Elements selected = info.select("b, strong");
Element next = selected.get(0);
Element now = null;
for (int i = 0; next != null ;i++) {
    now = next;
    next = null;
    Elements children = now.getAllElements();
    for (;selected.size() > i; i++) {
        next = selected.get(i);
        if (!children.contains(next)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //Do whatever with now & next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**:

**EDIT**

```
  info.select("b,strong").remove().text();
```

Comment: That will only get the header twice, just tested it on `<html><div><strong><strong>a</strong></strong></div><strong>b</strong></html>` and got the output: `<strong><strong>a</strong></strong>`

`<strong>a</strong>`

Comment: i tested it on firebug 1.2 extension and it worked for me. Ok try this way instead of using loop. Answer will be posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
doc.select("strong > strong, strong:last-child");
```